# How to reinitialize v-for component in vueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an array in my vuejs project. I'm rendering that array in my HTML file with `v-for`. And removing some elements from that rendered template by checking condition. When I wanted to reinitialize that array and rerendered it's not rendering all elements of the array. It's skipping removed elements. But, I want to initialize them.

This is my code:

```
            <div class="playground">

                <button @click="checkSort($event.target);" v-for="num in numArray" :value="num">
                    {{num}}
                </button>

            </div>
```

And here is the checkSort function to remove element from array.

```
        checkSort: function name(e) {
            let indexOfArr = this.numArray[this.index]

            if (indexOfArr == e.value) {
                console.log('milse')
                if (this.index == this.numArray.length - 1) {
                    console.log('full')
                    this.score += 100
                    this.numArray = null
                    this.numArray = this.generateUniqueArray(6, 40)
                    this.index = 0
                }
                this.score += 20
                this.index++
                e.remove()
            } else {
                this.numArray = this.generateUniqueArray(6, 40)
                this.index = 0
            }
        },
```

First time when the array initialize it looks like:
`[1,2,3,4,5,6]` I'm removing all the numbers inside the array when they get clicked after removing all I'm trying to regenerate a new array with some new number and the array generating but It's not rendering with all new numbers.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a computed property. Can you show your data and computed properties?

Comment: I solved it with splice method. I'm removing item by splice function and when the array gets empty it's automatically get initialized by a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with splice method. I'm removing an item by splice function and when the array gets empty it's automatically get initialized by a function

```
        checkSort: function (e) {
            let valueOfIndex = this.numArray[0]

            if (valueOfIndex == e.value) {
                if (0 == this.numArray.length - 1) {
                    this.score += 100
                    this.numArray = this.generateUniqueArray(6, 40)
                    this.shuffledArray = this.shuffle(this.numArray)
                }
                this.score += 20
                this.numArray.splice(0, 1)
            } else {
                this.numArray = this.generateUniqueArray(6, 40)
                this.shuffledArray = this.shuffle(this.numArray)
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you initialize your array in the `data` attribute, even if it starts out empty:

```js
data: {
  numArray: [],
}
```

2. Always assign a bind a `key` to each value in the array:

```js
<button
  @click="checkSort($event.target);"
  v-for="(num, index) in numArray"
  :value="num"
  :key="index"
>
  {{num}}
</button>
```